# What is the correct definition of render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning React and I frequently see the term render, whether it is as a method`ReactDOM.render()` or as mentioned in the React docs.

Looking up the definition of render brings two common definitions: 1) to cause to become / make 2) to provide. When describing `ReactDOM.render`, the official React docs explains it like so: "Render a React element into the DOM". Also, it mentions that a component could **render** another component.

So, for each of these scenarios, do they mean the same thing? Does that mean **rendering** = **providing** a React element? or **making**? Just want to grasp the meaning since this term is pervasive in React.